# Anyway to instruct dlopen not to load incompatible binary in C (Linux)

Tags: c, linux, 64-bit, 32-bit, dlopen

Is there a way to instruct dlopen to not to load a shared-object if it is not compatible?
For example calling dlopen from 64-bit binary application ideally should not load a 32-bit shared-object even if the "so" name matches. This can help in preventing from loading non-compatible binary to avoid un-expected behavior.

Comment: Did you try calling `dlerror()` (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlerror.3.html)?

Comment: Thank you Alk for your response, it is helpful. Looks like dlopen by default doesn't load any shared object if it is not compatible. However there is a misunderstanding from my side that resulted in this post, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to instruct dlopen to not to load a shared-object if it is not compatible?

There is *no need* for any such instruction: `dlopen` will already do *exactly* that.